# HLS "bufferStalledError" / "bufferNudgeOnStall"

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, hls.js

I'm trying to stream videos with HLS.js, and it works perfectly fine, but when I separate the audio from the video to support multiple audio tracks, it returns these two errors at random times in the video ("bufferStalledError" and "bufferNudgeOnStall").

I've tried using pure ffmpeg, I've tried using shaka packager, and I'm currently using bento4, but this error always occurs

(my bento4 code)

```sh
mp4hls --hls-version 4 -o "${outputFolder}" -f
[type=audio,+language=Japanese]"${inputFolder}${epFolder}/1080p.mp4"
[type=video]"${inputFolder}${epFolder}/1080p.mp4"
[type=video]"${inputFolder}${epFolder}/720p.mp4"
[type=video]"${inputFolder}${epFolder}/480p.mp4"
[type=video]"${inputFolder}${epFolder}/360p.mp4"
[type=video]"${inputFolder}${epFolder}/240p.mp4"
```

Comment: @CodingEdgar yeah, the problem was in the files, I generated them correctly and saved them in a certain location, but when I downloaded them back they corrupted and ended up giving this error